# Bootstrap 3 collapsing menu failing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am following a tutorial and it is teaching about collapsing menus and my code (What I can see) is like for like. But everything is working fine apart from the collpasing menu?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

        <div class="container">

            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Yo</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: On your third link menu, li tag is not closed properly ">" is missing.

Comment: That was a slight typo - it dosn't affect the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the bootstrap javascript and jQuery to your file? Those are needed to let the collapse-menu work, as far is a know.

And check if your tutorial is for Bootstrap 3, if you are using that, cause some Bootstrap 2 tutorials wont work for 3!

Comment: I am linked up to both and yes it is a bootstrap 3 tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4

Comment: I forgot to add http:// at the beginning of the jquery link - thanks for the heads up!